# RequestMapping not working in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have simple controler:

```
public class Controller {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public void test(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("HELLO WORLD");
    }
}
```

When I start jetty server and go to `localhost:8080/test` I am not getting output `System.out.println("HELLO WORLD");`

I have nothing about this controler in `web.xml`.

Where is a problem? How can I get my controler?

Comment: is your controller annotated with `@Controller` (you probaply should rename your class for convineince)? also check in the spring startup logs if the endpoint `/test` is registered

Comment: what @redflar3 said, make sure you've annotated with `@Controller`.

Comment: Thank you for your replye, but same problem

Comment: What response do you get instead?

Comment: @kaqqao  i am getting 404

Comment: @jefraedr Silly question, but is you app even deployed on root context? Maybe you should be targeting localhost:8080/subContext/test

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your class with @Controller

like

```
@Controller
public class AppController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public void test(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("HELLO WORLD");
    }
}
```

**Check for base package registred under Component Scanning**

> What is Component Scan?

Component scanning with `<context:component-scan base-package="<<your classes base package>>" />` in xml configuration and @ComponentScan in annotation based configuration is telling spring that it should search the class path for all the classes under<> and look at each class to see if it has a @Controller, or @Repository, or @Service, or @Component and if it does then Spring will register the class with the bean factory

Comment: Thank you for your replye, but same problem

Comment: make sure that you Controller is under the component scan in spring configuration

Comment: I dont understand you, what do you mean

Comment: are using xml based configuration or annotation based

Comment: I am using annotation for all mappings

Comment: I have updated my answer to explain what I want you to verify

Answer (score 0):

```
        @Controller
        @RequestMapping(value="/")
        public class AppController {
         @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
         public void test(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("HELLO WORLD");
          }
        }
```

add request mapping to your controller level then it works.